# MYSQL Database Design/SELECT Statement assistance

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm hoping someone may be able to provide some advice regarding a database schema I have created and a SELECT statement that I am using to query the database.

I am attempting to create a database of very old newspaper articles from the 1800's, storing such things as the date, title and full text of the article, an image of the article, the name of the newspaper the article came from, names of locations mentioned in the article and individuals mentioned within the article.

Basically below is the current structure I've created with tbArticle being the main table focus ("test" is the name of the database). I've normalised the name of the newspaper, image info, location info and individuals into their own tables and because it is assumed there will be many articles to many individuals, I've added a link table (lktbArticleIndividuals) of sorts between tbArticle & tbIndividual;

[image]

The reason for creating the database is to obviously make a focused set of newspaper articles searchable and store them in a logical format.

My issue or question is this ...

All I want to do is display a list of all the articles in the database, obviously including data from the other tables other than tbArticle and to do this I am using this SELECT query;

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbArticle a
     , tbLocation l
     , tbNewspapers n
     , tbIndividual i
     , lktbArticleIndividuals ai
     , tbImage m
 WHERE a.idLocation = l.idLocation 
   and a.idNewspaper = n.idNewspaper 
   and a.idArticle = ai.idArticle 
   and ai.idIndividual = i.idIndividual 
   and a.idImage = m.idImage;
```

Which does what I want ... except ... if more than one individual is listed as being in an article, then two (or more) instances of the whole article are returned with the only difference being the different individual's names being displayed.

If possible, I want to just list each article ONCE, but iterate through the two or more individuals to include them. Can this be done?

If I were to query the database in say PHP I suspect what I might have to do is some sort of loop within a loop to achieve the results I want, but this doesn't seem very efficient to me!!

Does any of this make sense to anyone?!

Comment: Well, maybe this *is* one of those rare instances where GROUP_CONCAT is handy

Comment: do a search for `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: On a side-note: please use the "new" join-syntax when writing joins as mentioned here: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `SELECT *`, you could name the columns you're interested in, and for things such as individuals, use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to add them all into one field, and at the end of your query, use `GROUP BY a.idArticle` to limit each article to one row per article.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want the first_name of each individual you could use a group by with a GROUP_CONCAT.

```
SELECT *,
       GROUP_CONCAT(i.firstname)
  FROM tbArticle a
     , tbLocation l
     , tbNewspapers n
     , tbIndividual i
     , lktbArticleIndividuals ai
     , tbImage m
 WHERE a.idLocation = l.idLocation 
   and a.idNewspaper = n.idNewspaper 
   and a.idArticle = ai.idArticle 
   and ai.idIndividual = i.idIndividual 
   and a.idImage = m.idImage;
GROUP BY a.idArticle
```

However, if you want to get many details of each individual I would encourage you to do two separate queries: one for the articles and another one to get the individuals of each article.

Comment: Be advised that there is a limit to the amount of characters you can fit into a 'GROUP_CONCAT', depending on your settings. If it's just a couple of names, you'd be fine, But I doubt you can fit hundreds in there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using GROUP_CONCAT ... is it only possible to do that with just one field? For example, you gave Firstname in your example above, would Firstname AND Lastname not be possible? I was suspecting this might be difficult and was thinking to splitting into two queries and as someone else has suggested this (you!) I may just end up doing this!

Comment: Yes it is possible: GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name)).

Just keep in mind the group_concat limit that @Nanne pointed out.